# Rails fast learning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi guys I need to know how can I learn rails effectively in a short time ! because I'm creating a simple app of sorting and I'm finding problems understanding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why's poignant guide to ruby.
rails in a nutshell

read the above books, come again.

Comment: thank you , because I'm kind of new to stack overflow I didn't pay attention, thanks again!

Comment: np. these are the two guys i read when i started with rails. helped out a lot. they are short, in depth, funny, and dont overload with extra data for advanced users.